# How to retrieve maximum value with their corresponding row using MAX function in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table with columns country(chararray), population(int),zone(int).
I need to find a country which has a greater population, where zone equal to 1. I need country name and population on the console.

I tried these statements after load.

```
fl = filter st by zone==1;
grp = group fl by zone;
result = foreach grp generate fl.country,MAX(fl.population);
dump result
```

It's giving me all the names and population. I can try 'Order by' and 'Limit', but I just need to use MAX function.

I tried to flatten operator, but it is asking me to try explicit cast.
Can you please verify it.

Here I am including the sample data

```
country,population,zone
india 3000 1
Australia 4000 2
US 5000 1
China 3000 1
Russia 500 1
```

Comment: Have you tried result = foreach grp generate group,MAX(fl.population);?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same can be accomplished this way:

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage(' ') as (c:chararray,p:int,z:int);
B = filter A by z==1;
C = foreach (group B all) {
    ordered = order B by p DESC; 
    limited = limit ordered 1; 
    generate flatten(limited)
}
dump C;
```

The main advantage of this approach over MAX is you can easily tweak it to give you the 'top K' (just replace the parameter of the limit statement).
Also, I think it uses less map-reduce jobs - filtering is done in the mapper, all the rest is done in the reducer. Using MAX+Filtering after it requires two jobs.

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
India 3000 1
Australia 4000 2
US 5000 1
China 3000 1
Russia 500 1
```

**Script**

```
A = LOAD 'test6.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (c:chararray,p:int,z:int);
B = FILTER A BY z==1;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,$1;
D = GROUP C ALL;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE MAX(C.p) as P;
F = FILTER C BY p == (int)E.P;
DUMP F;
```

**Output**

[image: Max]

Answer (score 1):

**Please solve it in simple steps:**

```
country = LOAD '/home/cloudera/pig/country_population.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (country:chararray, population:int, zone:int);

countryZone1 = filter country by zone == 1;

countryZone1Order = order countryZone1 by population DESC;

countryZone1Limit = limit countryZone1Order 1;

getMaxPopCountry = foreach countryZone1Limit generate country,population;

dump getMaxPopCountry;
```

**OutPut:**

(US,5000)

Answer (score 0):

use built-in TOP function to get the top **N** tuples of a bag

```
data = LOAD 'data' using PigStorage(' ') AS (c:chararray,p:int,z:int);
filtered = FILTER A by z==1;
grouped = GROUP filtered ALL;
max = FOREACH grouped {
    top = TOP(1,1,data);
    GENERATE FLATTEN(top);
}
DUMP max;
```